# cin and switch odd behaviour

Tags: c++, switch-statement, cin

So I'm having some problems when using `cin` and `switch` statements. 
First, the program prompts for an `int`:

```
cout << "How many registers would you like to use?: ";
cin >> kassor;
```

Later on, the user is asked to make a choice:

```
    cout << endl << "Press \"S\" to run the queue simulator and/or make a timestep." << endl;
    cout << "Press \"Q\" to quit." << endl << endl;
    cout << "Choice: ";
    cin >> choice;

    switch (choice)
    {
        case 's':
        case 'S':
        {
            cout << "test";
            nya = newCustomers();
            break;
        }
        case 'q':
        case 'Q':
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Here, the 'q' option works fine, but the 's' option does not. It 'hangs', as if still waiting for input. I have tried various `cin.ignore()` and such, but to no avail.

What puzzles me is that

```
switch (choice)
{
    case 's':
    case 'S':
    {
        cout << "test";
        nya = newCustomers();
        break;
```

Gives nothing, but the following:

```
switch (choice)
    {
        case 's':
        case 'S':
        {
            cout << "test";
            cin.ignore(1024, '\n');
            nya = newCustomers();
            break;
```

outputs 'test'.

My main question here is: Is the problem `cin` or something in the `case: s` ?

Thank's in advance :

Comment: Put a `cout.flush();` after your test output. That should make the text appear. As for your hanging issue, it must be something in `newCustomers()`. Does it still hang even if you comment that out?

Comment: yes, the 'test' appears now :) It still hangs, even though I comment it out. In reality, I have five home-made functions in `case c`. I didn't want to post it all, as it is around 300 lines :)

Comment: 300 lines for five cases in a switch statement? Too big. Refactor the code so that the operations for each case are in a separate function, and call the appropriate function for each case.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the function `newCustomers` is getting hung up on a stray character or two after the input to `choice`. That would explain why the `ignore` call "fixes" the problem, and it's the solution suggested in the comment by @TheBuzzSaw.

To see this more clearly, change

```
cout << "test";
```

to

```
cout << "test\n";
```

or to

```
cout << "test" << std::endl;
```

On some systems the console is line-buffered, so you won't see any output until the program writes a newline. Inserting `endl` flushes the output buffer, so you should see the message even if subsequent code hangs. Or change it to:

```
cerr << "test\n";
```

`cerr` is more aggressive about flushing buffers, precisely because it's used for error output that you don't want to miss.

Comment: My understanding is that only `std::endl` flushes the buffer. Instances of `\n` in the string itself generally do not flush from what I've seen.

Comment: as `newCustomers()` does not take input, can it really be hung up by something from `cin`? Although the `cerr` outputs `test`, the program still hangs after that.

Comment: @koldrakan, it is possible. Is you `cin` inside of a loop to continually take input?

Comment: yes, the whole `case` is in a `while` loop. It hangs on the first lap in the loop.

Comment: @TheBuzzSaw - I didn't mean to suggest that '\n' flushes the buffer; that's an OS thing, not a language thing. It might or it might not.

Comment: the strange thing is that it accepts the 'q' case without question. This is what leads me to believe the error is in one of my own functions

Comment: @koldrakan - okay, now you've trickled out a bit more information about the real code. Still seems like stray characters hanging up the input somewhere in the code you haven't shown.

Comment: @koldrakan - the 'q' case does something rather different.

Comment: @PeteBecker - if you want, I could post the entire code. I was hesitant to do it, since people tend to dislike large beasts :)

Comment: What you should post is the smallest sample that you can come up with that compiles and runs and illustrates the problem. Often reducing the code to an example like that helps you see for yourself where the problem is. It's a useful skill to develop.

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer:** 
I believe cin is failing somewhere or it is the cause of unexpected behavior
I cannot pinpoint it without more code.

**Edit:** I cannot post a comment on your post, so I figured I would post here. The "hanging" could be an infinite loop. If you are doing something like what I am doing and looping to get input and fail to clear the error bits cin will constantly fail. If you are not cout'ing something each time you ask for input it could just be quietly sitting there looping through that input-gathering function. Put breakpoints in all of your loops and step through with the debugger to verify none of your loops are infinite looping.

Try adding a std::cin.clear(); before the .ignore() in your second test case. See if that stops your hanging.

**Explanation:**

cin can fail. This can cause weird behavior. A common way for it to fail is if you are reading into an integer and you get character input. Once cin fails it sets a fail bit and from then on, cin does not behave like you would expect.

I would recommend not using a bare cin >> choice, because it can fail and you wont know it. I would abstract this out to a method that gets the proper input you want.

I personally keep a tiny utility library(.h) and .cpp around to include in projects where I am using common functionality I have already coded.

I have a readIntBetween() function which accepts 2 integers and reads from standard input an integer between those two numbers. If the user does not provide the right input (integer over or under bounds, or input containing a character) I ask them to re-enter the input.

In this function I make sure to clear the fail bits when I have detected a failure, and I ignore something like 200 characters to "flush" it out.

Here is the code to my readIntBetween function. I hope it helps you diagnose your error and fix it:

```
int readIntBetween(int lower, int upper, std::string prompt)
{
    bool goodVal = false;
    int value = -1;
    do
    {
        std::cout << prompt ;
        std::cin >> value;

        if ( value >= lower && value <= upper)//check to make sure the value is in between upper and lower
            goodVal = true;
        else
        {
            if(std::cin.fail())
            {
                std::cout << "\tError - invalid format for integer number" << std::endl;

                //clear all status bit including fail bit
                std::cin.clear();

                //flush input buffer to discard invalid input
                std::cin.ignore(1000, '\n');

            }
            else
            std::cout << "Value is not valid, must be between " << lower<<" and "<<upper<<"."<<std::endl;
        }



    }while(!goodVal);
    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `cin` is being used inside a loop, I recommend a different approach.

```
char buffer[64];
cin.getline(buffer, 64);

char choice = buffer[0];

switch (choice)
{
    ...
}
```

It is possible your `cin` is not being reset, and any extraneous characters are being fed into the subsequent requests for input. Grab more input and only process its first character.

Comment: the strange thing is that it accepts the 'q' case without question. This is what leads me to believe the error is in one of my own functions.

Comment: Add `cout << "DONE" << endl;` after your call to `newCustomers()`. I'm curious to know exactly *where* it is hanging.